# React state object updates in console but not in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a small React app that processes and then re-renders a few different state objects when a button is clicked. For two of them (stocks, accounts), they render fine using the setState function, but for the items in gameplayHandler(), they render to the console but not to the browser. They don't strictly need their own component, like the other two do.

I think I'm doing something quite obvious wrong - could anyone give me a tip on how to get all of the below rendering?

Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import {stocks, accounts, gameplay} from './dummy_data/data'
import Stock from './Stock/Stock'
import Account from './Account/Account'

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        stocks: stocks,
        accounts: accounts,
        gameplay: gameplay
}

 sleep = () => {
    this.stockHandler()
    this.accountHandler()
    this.gameplayHandler()
}

gameplayHandler = () => {

    let netWorth = this.state.accounts.reduce(function(prevAcc,curAcc){
        return prevAcc + curAcc.balance
        },
    0)

     this.setState({
        gameplay: [
            {
                playerName: gameplay.playerName,
                gameDay: gameplay.gameDay += 1,
                netWorth: netWorth.toFixed(2)
            }
        ]
    })
}

accountHandler = () => {
    this.state.accounts.map(newAccount => {
        const interestPayment = parseFloat(((newAccount.balance / 100) * newAccount.interestRate).toFixed(2))
        newAccount.balance = Math.round((newAccount.balance + interestPayment) * 100) / 100
        })

    return this.setState({
        accounts: accounts
    })
}

stockHandler = () => {
     this.state.stocks.map(newStock => {
        newStock.currentPrice *=2
    })

    this.setState({
        stocks: stocks,
    })
}

render() {
    let accounts = null
    if (this.state.accounts) {
        accounts = (
            <div>
                {this.state.accounts.map(account => {
                    return <Account key={account.key} name={account.name} balance={account.balance}/>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }

    let stocks = null
    if (this.state.stocks) {
        stocks = (
            <div>
                {this.state.stocks.map(stock => {
                    return <Stock key={stock.key} name={stock.name} currentPrice={stock.currentPrice}/>
                })}
            </div>
        )

        return (
            <div className="App">
                > Gameplay:
                <div>Player Name: {this.state.gameplay.playerName}, Game Day: {this.state.gameplay.gameDay}, Job Title: {this.state.gameplay.jobTitle}, Net Worth: £{this.state.gameplay.netWorth}</div>
                > Stocks:
                { stocks }
                > Accounts:
                { accounts }
                <button onClick={this.sleep}>Go =></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

}

export default App

Comment: When an update to the state requires access to the current state and/or props, use the updater parameter in the `setState` signature like this:  `this.setState((prevState, props) => { ...`

Answer (score 0):

It is weird because first of all you need to bind `gameplayHandler` function.So it should be like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        stocks: stocks,
        accounts: accounts,
        gameplay: gameplay
    };
    this.gameplayHandler = this.gameplayHandler.bind(this);
  }
```

Otherwise, it should have give an error when you try `setState` and of course you should bind `accountHandler` and `stockHandler` functions. Can you tell me the issue is exist even if you bind these functions?